# Getting wifi errors

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, network-interface, troubleshooting

I've been unable to get WiFi reliably working firstly on Ubuntu and now on Arch. It potentially seems like a hardware issue, but it was flawless on Windows - then I switched to Ubuntu and it would occasionally connect after many times of trying, but it wouldn't last for long. I thought it was just a problem with Ubuntu so I switched to Arch but it's remained. And when it does work then it's painfully slow.

When I run wifi-menu I get the following:

```
Scanning for networks... Could not set interface wlp3s0 flags (UP): Input/output error
n180211: Could not set interface 'wlp3s0' UP
Could not set interface wlp3s0 flags (UP): Input/output error
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlp3s0' UP
wlp3s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
failed
```

But again, this is only when it stops working. Generally what happens is I turn on my computer, and the WiFi "works" although I need to keep reconnecting and it's very slow. Then after a while it cuts out seemingly permanently, and this is when the above errors occur.

I don't think it could be a hardware issue because it would be a massive coincidence for it to happen on the same day that I switch from Windows to Ubuntu. But the IO errors make me question this.

All other devices are fine so it's definitely my computer, unfortunately I don't have any other network to test with.

Comment: If you suspect a hardware issue, it would be very useful to tell us which hardware; specifically A) the make of the computer B) the model obtained from the serial number plate (specific reason for that) C) the make and model of the WiFi adapter. Please click [edit] and add those to the original question so all may see; please do not click Add Comment as Comments can stack up and get hidden.

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`